# Why DLL function calls are not compiled to relative CALL instructions

Tags: visual-studio, dll, x86, dllimport

When I call a function *DLLFunction(int)*, which is defined in a DLL. Visual Studio 2013 on my Intel X86 PC compiles it to the following instruction

`CALL [__imp__DLLFunction@4]         // Call absolute indirect address
 FF 15 00 90 40 00  CALL [00409000h] // original absolute CALL instruction
 FF 15 00 90 39 01  CALL [01399000h] // After address fixup by OS loader
// __imp__DLLFunction@4 is the IAT entry address for DLLFunction, where there stores the address for DLLFunction().`

IAT's RVA (Relative Visual Address) in the caller image is 0x9000, where there stores import functions' addresses.

`RVA     Import Function Address
0x9000  0x60fd1014  // DLLFunction
0x9004  0x60fdxxxx  // someOtherDLLFunction0
0x9008  0x60fdxxxx  // someOtherDLLFunction1
...`

> Why compiler does not generate relative CALL instruction?

If using relative CALL instruction, the loader does not need to fix up the addresses for all these CALL instructions like this.

Answer (score 2):

`CALL [__imp__DLLFunction@4]` is not calling the usual stub that steers the control to the imported function through an indirect jump, it is calling the imported function directly through the pointer in the IAT.

This happens when the external function is annotated with `__declspec(dllimport)` (and possibly in any way that makes the compilers aware of the programmer intent).

Without it, the compiler generates a relative (near) call and the linker add the stub.

```
:401005 E806000000     call 401010h              ;Relative near call to the stub
... The stub ...
:401010 FF25F4B04000   jmp DWORD PTR [0040b0f4]  ;Indirect abs jump
```

With the intent clear, the code above transforms to

```
:401005 FF15F4B04000   call DWORD PTR [0040b0f4]
```

that is using an absolute indirect call.
This spares a jump but requires an additional fix-up at load time, a relative indirect call would be effectively better but, unfortunately, it doesn't exist.

x86-64 code can use RIP-relative addressing to mitigate the fix-up problems.

Comment: I was wondering if this is what was really going on.  This is essentially identical to what happens on Linux when you compile with `-fno-plt`: indirect `call` using a function pointer from the GOT (Global Offset Table).  This makes a lot more sense than what the OP was claiming happened.

Comment: @PeterCordes AFAIK Windows executables work this way. I tested it with VS 2013 to be sure, before posting. I've never encountered a case like the OP's one but maybe something changes in the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

**update: I didn't read the question carefully**: the indirect `call` target is still inside the executable, and is itself an indirect `jmp`, according to the OP.

The answer below is discussing making the `call rel32` go *directly* into the DLL.

---

That would require modifying the machine code at every `call` instruction to put in the right offset during dynamic loading of a DLL.  (You don't know what address the DLL will be loaded at, so you don't know the `rel32` distance between the executable and the DLL at link time of the executable.)

Using a table of function pointers puts all the relocation stuff in one place where it can be written efficiently while dynamic linking.

It also couldn't reach far enough in 64-bit code if a DLL was loaded more than 2GB away from code that needed to call it.

---

IIRC, Windows does support the scheme you describe for DLLs that you link normally (with the linker at compile time, not with a runtime dll import). 
 Every DLL has a "preferred" load address, and code that calls it optimistically uses `call rel32` instructions so every call site needs fixups if that address isn't available.  These fixups happen while the process is being loaded.  With [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) enabled, DLLs won't load at the same address every time.

**Once the process is already running, its code pages will be read-only**, so if these fixups are needed, it's a problem.  This is probably why dynamic DLL imports don't use this mechanism.  (The implementation could use `VirtualProtect` to make code pages writeable for these fixups, but **it wouldn't be thread-safe to have two different threads importing DLLs at the same time**.  One thread might make a page read-only after it was done, but while another thread was still writing fixups to that page, resulting in a fault.)

Also, cross-modifying code isn't in general safe.  Other threads could be running instructions in the same function where you were applying a fixup.  You could atomically store the new `rel32` using an `xchg` or something.  This might be safe.

BTW, on Linux, even "normal" libraries like `libc` are called through a level of indirection like this (function-pointer from the Global Offset Table).  See [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/).

It's partly a tradeoff between overhead of runtime dynamic linking (load times) vs. performance after it's loaded.

Comment: Hi Peter, your answer is inverse. Is it right? That would **not** require modifying the machine code at every call instruction to put in the right offset during dynamic loading of a DLL if using **relative CALL**.

Comment: @ZhiboShen: No, you don't know where the DLL will be loaded relative to the main executable, but all the relative offsets hard-code that distance.  `call rel32` works *inside* a position-independent library or executable, but needs fixups between separately-loaded libraries.

Comment: Hi Peter, Visual Studio on X86 uses IAT. Absolute addresses of functions from another DLL are stored in the IAT of the calling thread, which has to be fixed up by OS loader. **CALL rel32** is calling rel32 from IAT. Althought we don't know where the DLL will be loaded relative the main thread, the IAT and .text are both in the calling thread address region, and their address relativity remains the same.

Comment: @ZhiboShen: I'm not familiar with many of the details of dynamic linking on Windows.   Sorry I didn't read the question carefully and missed the part about the `call` target being an indirect `jmp [mem]`.  That does seem like a missed optimization.  Can you please update the question so that's in a code block, too, so people skimming quickly don't miss it?

Comment: @ZhiboShen: have you checked that the `call` still goes through the `jmp` after DLL import?  Maybe something updates the call-target table so it bypasses the `jmp`?  e.g. single-step into a `call` with a debugger, after it's already been called at least once.

Comment: I update my question. Sorry that I made a mistake.  `call` target is not an indirect `jmp [mem]`, it is the IAT entry address for `DLLFunction`, where there stores the address for `DLLFunction()`.